# CSS Overflow Issues with Modal POPUP & AdSense

Tags: css, popup, modal-dialog, overlay, adsense

I use OUIBounce ( https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce )exit popup.

When it fires, if there is AdSense ad unit under the popup, the AdSense is 100% visible, while the rest of the site is greyed out.

Please help me fix this.

Here is underlay CSS

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s;
animation: fadein 0.5s;
```

Screenshot:

Note that all content is greyed out, while AdSense unit is visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the script used to fire the modal, add a callback function (after cookieExpire: 10,):

```
callback: function() { 
 $("#ouibounce-modal").css({"z-index": "100"});
}
```

Comment: How do you know `100` will help?

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm not 100% sure it works. It worked for me on 2 different sites. Maybe a more general approach is needed. Maybe my answer can help someone. Do you think this is better: `$("body *").css({"z-index": "0 !important"});
$("#ouibounce-modal").css({"z-index": "100"});`?